# Needs to check with first 5 digits of the number variable in db2 stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, substring

I Needs to check with first 5 digits of the number variable in stored procedure.
Please Find the below example.

SP:

```
IN "IN_CNBR" VARCHAR(100),

DECLARE v_end VARCHAR(16);
```

v_end is fetched from the DB and it may have a value of digit up to 16..
But i have to split the first 5 digit of the v_end and have to check with input parameter

and i have a check,

```
IF (((CAST(IN_CNBR AS BIGINT)) > (CAST(v_end AS BIGINT))))
```

Is the below one is possible?

```
v_end:=v_end.substring(0,5);
```

then

```
IF (((CAST(IN_CNBR AS BIGINT)) > (CAST(v_end AS BIGINT))))
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Yes it is possible.  What language is the stored procedure written in?

Comment: its SQL Dan.. can you provide me the syntax for the same, as i surfed a lot , but couldn't able to reach ,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a variable to the first five characters of itself as follows:

```
set v_end = left(v_end,5);
```

or

```
set v_end = substr(v_end,1,5);
```

Note that DB2 `substr` uses one-based indexing.